# Primefaces push and Wildfly

Tags: primefaces, websocket, push, wildfly

Has anyone managed to get wildfly's undertow to work with Primefaces push 2.0? Wildfly's native websockets (jee7) works great on it's own. I'm not sure how to integrate with primefaces. Any examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on WildFly 8.1.0.Final with:

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>    
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PrimePushServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PrimePushServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in .xhtml:

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/#{request.remoteUser}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(facesmessage) {
        var msgdetail = $.base64.decode(facesmessage.detail);
        facesmessage.detail = msgdetail;
        PF('growlWidget').show([ facesmessage ]);
    }
</script>
```

My Resource:

```
@PushEndpoint("/{user}")
@Singleton
public class UserResource {

@PathParam("user")
private String user;

@OnMessage(encoders = { JSONEncoder.class }, decoders = { JSONDecoder.class })
public FacesMessage onMessage(FacesMessage message) {
    return message;
}
```

The javascript-part should be modified to match your demand.

Comment: Thank you for this response, I have tried it and I am getting:org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor cannot be cast to org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationProcessor
Using PM 5.1 and atmosphere 2.2.0
any suggestions?

Comment: while i'm tring this gets error like this SEVERE: Servlet [Push Servlet] in web application [/bstfo] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.inject.PathParamIntrospector

Answer (score 1):

Wildfly 9.0.2

pom.xml

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
                <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>5.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PrimePushServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>PrimePushServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
```

xhtml

```
<p:socketonMessage="handleMessage" channel="/counter" />
```

js

```
function handleMessage(data) {
    console.log(data);
```

}

Java

```
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint;
import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;

@PushEndpoint("/counter")
public class MessageResources {

@OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
public String onMessage(String count) {
    return count;
}
}
```

More java

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.primefaces.push.EventBus;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBusFactory;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class GlobalMessageControler implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4507223739929042795L;
    private volatile int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void increment() {
        count++;

        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish("/counter", String.valueOf(count));
    }
}
```